# Should I migrate ADAL to MSAL in my timer app?

Tags: azure-functions

I've written a timer function to pull events from Defender API and forward to LogAnalytics, using ADAL to authenticate and get tokens via device code then refresh token cycling. As support for ADAL is ending June 2022, logically I should migrate to MSAL under normal circumstances.

However, as I've used ADAL as part of a stateless azure function (that holds the refresh token in a durable entity), what's the point in migrating? From what I can see the benefits of migrating to MSAL is that the refresh token is cached in memory instead of needing to manually store it, but that means nothing to me as my function won't hold that cache across invocations anyway.

With this in mind, is there a valid reason I should specifically migrate to MSAL when it seems like it would just complicate the process as I can't use the benefits migrating should offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important reason to swap over is not feature updates, it is the lack of any [security updates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/update-your-applications-to-use-microsoft-authentication-library/ba-p/1257363) after 2022. It is also possible that there would be some form of endpoint change in the future that would completely break the library, such as what will happen to the Azure AD Graph endpoints.

It is entirely possible that this will never be an issue for you, but by updating before June 2022 you can unsure you won't be in a situation where your application breaks or has a known security hole that you have to fix quickly.